# How to Programatically Add Quotes to Windows File/Directory Names w

Tags: find, git-bash, rm

I am using Git for windows to find and remove files using the linux `find` and `rm` commands. Some of the file/directory names in the paths returned by `find` command have spaces such as in the case of "program files" windows directory.

Running the `find` and `rm` commands **as shown below** will return errors because of the spaces in file/directory names. How can I remove these files programatically without receiving errors from the `rm` command?

```
$ find /c/'program files'/ ~ -type f -iname "securecrt.vbs" 2>/dev/null
/c/program files/VanDyke Software/Clients/Scripts/securecrt.vbs
$
```

```
$ find /c/'program files'/ ~ -type f -iname "securecrt.vbs" 2>/dev/null | xargs rm
rm: cannot remove '/c/program': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'files/VanDyke': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Software/Clients/Scripts/securecrt.vbs': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a -exec directive:

```
find /c/'program files'/ ~ -type f -iname "securecrt.vbs" -exec rm {} \;
```

That does work even with files inclulding space in their name.